# How do I know which API endpoints are available on a specific plan?

Tags: docusignapi

My client wants to integrate with DocuSign but has a limited budget, enough to cover the DocuSign Basic API plan. This plan has limited functionality compared to the Intermediate and Advanced plans.
Meanwhile a Developer account has access to all features.

How do I know which endpoints I can use if I'm targeting a Basic API plan, such that when I go live, I know my integration will work on the Basic API plan?

Answer (score 0):

The way we typically approach this problem is by ensuring that your client account can be used to perform the operations that your integration will be doing.

So, say client comes with requirement - I want your app to do X.
Ask them - can you do X manually from the web app?

If they can - your app will be able to do it.

It's not really "which API endpoints" but which features. The same endpoint can be used for multiple features and vice versa.

Explore with your client what they want to do, ensure they can do it from the web app - and then you can use the API to do it without any issues.

Comment: Thanks for this @Inbar. My client doesn't yet have a DocuSign account and she wants to know if it can do what we need. Is there not a comprehensive list of which features are available on which plans. What you describe seems very hap hazard.

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/products-and-pricing this is the list, but for more details you'll need to contact our sales team. The reason I suggested this approach is because this is not done on the endpoint level. The same endpoint, depending on what parameters you use - will work for some plans, features.
So, you should start by understanding what your customer wants and ask the sales team to give them a quote.